# Reading CSV from URL previously worked, now returning error

Tags: r, noaa

I have a program that I intended to rerun regularly with minimal code-manipulation. The code below previously ran succcessfully, but it stopped working. I thought, perhaps the server was down, but when I pasted the URL on my browser, it initiated a download of the csv file. So I think I'm missing something...

```
nyc_temp_data <- read.csv("https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/access/services/data/v1?dataset=daily-summaries
  &dataTypes=TMAX&stations=USW00094728&startDate=2014-01-01&endDate=2020-05-01&includeAttributes=true&units=standard&format=csv")
```

When I ran it today, I get the following error:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open URL 'https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/access/services/data/v1?dataset=daily-summaries
  &dataTypes=TMAX&stations=USW00094728&startDate=2014-01-01&endDate=2020-05-01&includeAttributes=true&units=standard&format=csv': HTTP status was '400 '
```

Answer (score 0):

Sub-optimal solution but gets the job done:

```
# Store the url: csv_url => character vector
csv_url <- "https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/access/services/data/v1?dataset=daily-summaries
&dataTypes=TMAX&stations=USW00094728&startDate=2014-01-01&endDate=2020-05-01&includeAttributes=true&units=standard&format=csv"

# Store the full filepath to the desired output location / filename: 
# output_fpath => character vector
output_fpath <- paste0(getwd(), "/nyc_temp_data.csv")

# Download the url and store it at the filepath: nyc_temp_data.csv => stdout
download.file(csv_url, output_fpath)

# Read in the csv from the file path. nyc_temp_data => data.frame
nyc_temp_data <- read.csv(output_fpath)
```